# SVN Write through proxy prerequisites

Tags: svn

We are planning to set up a write through proxy.The Master SVN version is 1.8.8 and it is on revision r1568071 currently. My question before proceeding this setup is "Is there a necessity to fix the Master SVN repository since we have tons of svn loads which have by passed the svn prop validation.Will the svnsync complete without any errors? We have even tried to fix the repository, but the fix fails due to the below errors,

```
svnadmin: E185001: Svndiff contains a too-large window
svnadmin: E140001: zlib (uncompress): corrupt data: Decompression of svndiff data failed
```

Please let me know if these errors occur while svnsync.